# Is it possible to increase width of UITabBarItem in Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm using Xamarin.iOS and have a `UITabBar`. Could anyone please tell me how can we increase width of an individual `UITabBarItem`? Any suggestions really appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set this via the `UITabBar` by setting the desired `ItemWidth`.

E.g., `myTabBar.ItemWidth = 50.f`

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/UIKit.UITabBar.ItemWidth/